# Use marathon as GUI test

Tags: java, swing, testing, marathontesting

I use marathon for testing GUI and run it with own UI and work properly with this UI.  I need to run it without own UI for example by shell script or other language. How to run it without own UI  and with console and other scripting language even in JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marathon has a batch option where it executes without a UI.

Try marathon -help which should give you the options.